# OnClickListener to the Fragment Class

Tags: android, android-fragments

if i click `FridgeWarningStatus Fragment` then it will occupy full screen? how can i do that???
please any one help me thanks in Advance

```
public class FridgeContainer extends Fragment {

private View view;
private FridgeTimerStatus fridgeTimerStatus;
private FridgeWarningStatus fridgeWarningStatus;
private FridgeStatus fridgeStatus;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fridge_container,container,false);

fridgeWarningStatus = (FridgeWarningStatus)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fridge_timer_status);
    fridgeTimerStatus = (FridgeTimerStatus)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fridge_timer_status);

    fridgeStatus = (FridgeStatus)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fridge_status);


    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want full screen why don't you use Activity, Instead of Fragment?

If you want to use fragment then remove action bar of activity, design your fragment view like wise.

If any dought please ask.

Comment: i have to replace the another fragment into that fragment.So that i m using Fragment. and the doubt is I am having one fragment consists of three fragments from top to down. If i touch on top Fragment like FridgeWarningStatus, remaining two fragments will disappear with animation and FridgeWarningStatus will occupy the full screen.

Comment: You can hide your two fragment, Run time increase size dynamically of layout your main fragment which you want to show full screen.

Comment: how can i hide my two fragments? Can u please tell me through some example?

Comment: Use Fragment manger class , 1  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager(); 2 ft.hide(You Fragment name to hide); 3 ft.commit();

Comment: when we press back button then how can I show same 3 fragments?

Comment: Fragment frag= new YourFragmentName();      
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.frame_container, frag);
ft.remove(HomeFragment.this);
ft.addToBackStack(HomeFragment.class.getName());
ft.commit();

Comment: On back back button press you can get your previous fragment. By using this code.

Comment: how can i access Id's of second and third fragments in 1st fragment layout?

Answer (score 0):

In other words, you want FridgeWarningStatus fills the screen? you may also post the file R.layout.fridge_container?

Comment: fridge_container fragment contains these three fragments.

Comment: If you want to put in place a fragment of another fragment must use 'Fragment Transaction' and use the 'replace' method

Comment: [http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-fragment-transaction-fragmentmanager-and-backstack.html](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-fragment-transaction-fragmentmanager-and-backstack.html)[http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-fragment-transaction-fragmentmanager-and-backstack.html]

Comment: I had the same problem some time ago, I had a fragment with two fragment within and at the click of a button one disappeared and the other was in full screen. I solved this by putting a fragment into a linear layout giving weight to both layout in the xml file, and the click of a button I changed the weight of the main class of one of the fragment and the other was in full screen.